# Custom view's onDraw receives canvas with different sizes

Tags: android, android-canvas, ondraw

I have a class derived from ImageView:

```
public class TouchView extends ImageView
{
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
   ...
```

The touchview is created only once in the activity's onCreate and populated with a drawable from a SVG file.

```
ImageView imageView = new TouchView(this);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
FrameLayout f = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame2);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams l = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
f.addView(imageView, l);
...
is = openFileInput(svgname);
svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(is);
is.close();

Drawable d = svg.createPictureDrawable();
imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

All the environment remains the same all the time. Yet in the onDraw method I'm getting canvas with different sizes between the events. That is the code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
  super.onDraw(canvas);
  Log.v("DRAW", " w= " + canvas.getWidth() + " h=" + canvas.getHeight());
  ...
}
```

produces logs with lines, where width and height of the canvas change back and forth from normal 1024*728 (this is the correct view dimension on the tablet) to 200*160 (strange thing introducing bugs in my drawings). I'm embarrassed.

Should the canvas be always of the same size for the same view/drawable? The documentation says that getWidth and getHeight methods return dimensions of the current drawing *layer*, but it's not clear what is the layer, how many of them is created for the canvas "behind the scene" and how to control this process.

I'd appreciate any explanation on how to get consistent drawing behaviuor, specifically by getting actual size of the view being painted in `onDraw`.

Currently I'm using a workround with a call to the view's getDrawingRect, but I'm not sure it is a proper way, because it seems that the `canvas` parameter of `onDraw` should be all-sufficient for drawing sizing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here is how I got this fixed, hope it helps you

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
    // resize
Matrix resize = new Matrix();
resize.postScale((float)Math.min(w, h) / (float)mMarker.getWidth(), (float)Math.min(w, h) / (float)mMarker.getHeight());
imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMarker, 0, 0, mMarker.getWidth(), mMarker.getHeight(), resize, false);

c.drawBitmap(imageScaled, 0,0, paint);

}
```

Where mMarker is defined in the custom ImageView constructor.

```
...
private Bitmap mMarker, imageScaled;
Paint paint = new Paint();


//Java constructor
public AvatarImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

//XML constructor
public AvatarImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    // load the image only once
    mMarker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.silhouette_48);
    mMarker.setHasAlpha(true);paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);

    //invalidate(); // don't know if I need this
}
```